# microsoft tag download barcode to disk

Tags: php

I am using microsoft tag php library by Scott Vanderbeck.

It has a function to output the barcode to browser as an image to browser, but I would like download and save to disk. My goal is to loop through all the tags and download each barcode as an image onto a disk. I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is my code
require_once('MSTag_v2.php');

```
$MSTagAuthToken = "your token";

//Create an MSTag interface instance
$msTag = new MSTag();

//Create User Credentials
$userCredential = new UserCredential($MSTagAuthToken);


//Display Microsoft Tag image in browser
$result = $msTag->GetBarcode($userCredential,'MAIN','Cyclamen coum Pewter','jpeg',1);

if($result)
{
    ob_start();
        $length = strlen($result);
        header('Last-Modified: '.date('r'));
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Length: '.$length);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        print($result);
    ob_end_flush();
    exit;
} 
else
{
    echo $msTag->getLastException();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the images directly to disk

```
if($result)
{
    file_put_contents($filename, $result);
}
```

Just generate a filename for each so you do not overwrite them (maybe use [tempnam()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.tempnam.php)).